# Illegal assignment from LIST to SET?

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

How assign List To Set and Set to List?
While updating some Existing records I need to avoid the Duplicates , How can I use Set To List and List to Set, While executing the following code getting the above error. can any one help me wt is wrong in my code..

```
public List<id> sitecontractids = new List<id>();
public List<Engineer_Checklist__c> ssnewList = new List<Engineer_Checklist__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> finalscnewlist = new List<SiteContracts__c>();
public List<SiteContracts__c> scList = new List<SiteContracts__c>();
public set<SiteContracts__c> scnewset = new set<SiteContracts__c>();
    scnewset =[SELECT Id,(Select id from Service_Sheets__r WHERE
                    Fire_Extinguisher_Service_complete__c=True ORDER BY  createdDate DESC ) FROM SiteContracts__c LIMIT 200];

 for(SiteContracts__c scnewid :scnewset ){
         sitecontractids.add(scnewid.id);
   }
    ssnewList =[Select Id, X6L_Water_Qty__c, X9L_Water_Qty__c,
            From Engineer_Checklist__c 
            Where Fire_Extinguisher_Service_complete__c=true AND Site_Contract__c !=NULL AND
                 Site_Contract__c IN :sitecontractids  ORDER BY  createdDate DESC LIMIT 200];
 for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli:ssnewList)
{
    SiteContracts__c newsc = new SiteContracts__c();
newsc.id=ssli.Site_Contract__c;
newsc.X6L_Water__c=ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c;
newsc.X9L_Water__c=ssli.X9L_Water_Qty__c;

scnewset.add(newsc);
}
finalscnewList.addall(sclist);
update finalscnewList;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid duplicates based on the SObject field values you can put the new objects straight into a set but you'll have to turn the set back into a list to do the insert/update/upsert:

```
Set<SiteContracts__c> newSet = new Set<SiteContracts__c>();
for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli:ssnewList)
{
    SiteContracts__c newsc = new SiteContracts__c();
    newsc.id=ssli.Site_Contract__c;
    newsc.X6L_Water__c=ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c;
    newsc.X9L_Water__c=ssli.X9L_Water_Qty__c;
    newSet.add(newsc);
}
upsert new List<SiteContracts__c>(newSet);
```

or if you already had the new objects in a list you could convert that to a set (and so eliminate the duplicates) like this:

```
List<SiteContracts__c> newList = new List<SiteContracts__c>();
...
Set<SiteContracts__c> newSet = new Set<SiteContracts__c>(newList);
upsert new List<SiteContracts__c>(newSet);
```

It is fairly rare to be checking for duplicates like this in Apex code; usually duplicate checks would be based on specific fields not all fields.

**PS**

From the comments, it appears that the problem is that Engineer_Checklist__c is a child object of SiteContracts__c and that the code is trying to update the same SiteContracts__c object multiple times because there are many Engineer_Checklist__c objects being queried for each SiteContracts__c. So there is also a logical problem here: which of the many child Engineer_Checklist__c values should be pushed into the parent SiteContracts__c object?

A quick fix to the immediate problem would be avoid the duplicates by using a set of the ID values  (and arbitrarily taking the values from the first Engineer_Checklist__c):

```
List<SiteContracts__c> updateList = new List<SiteContracts__c>();
Set<Id> handledContractIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Engineer_Checklist__c ssli:ssnewList)
{
    if (!handledContractIds.contains(ssli.Site_Contract__c)) {
        SiteContracts__c newsc = new SiteContracts__c();
        newsc.id=ssli.Site_Contract__c;
        newsc.X6L_Water__c=ssli.X6L_Water_Qty__c;
        newsc.X9L_Water__c=ssli.X9L_Water_Qty__c;
        updateList.add(newsc);
        handledContractIds.add(ssli.Site_Contract__c);
    }
}
update upddateList;
```

Comment: Hi Keith, I did as u suggested but getting Duplicate ID ERROR:System.ListException: Duplicate id in list : ..........

Comment: @KartiK See the answer PS.

Answer (score 0):

SOQL query returns List of records.Please change to list instead of set in query.

Comment: Also Set is only for primitive types.  You can't have a set against a complex type like an sobject.

Comment: @willard If you run `System.assertEquals(2, new Set<Contact>{new Contact(LastName = 'Doe'), new Contact(LastName = 'Smith'), new Contact(LastName = 'Doe')}.size());` you will see that sets do have defined behaviour for SObjects.

Comment: huh - learn something new every day.  thanks keith for the clarification.