# List Exception Duplicate id error

Tags: trigger, list

I get an error in my trigger when i tried to insert bulk data from data loader. Error is :

> ERROR: SubscriberUpdateTrigger: execution of AfterInsertcaused by:
>   System.ListException: Duplicate id in list:
>   a058000000Cdj8DAARTrigger.SubscriberUpdateTrigger: line 67, column 1

I have use listBundleToUpdate as Set and then tried to insert it to convert into list.

```
line 67
List<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> subs = new List<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>(listBundleToUpdate);
UPDATE subs;
```

## My Trigger

```
trigger SubscriberUpdateTrigger on Subscriber__c (after Insert, after Update, after undelete) {

    Set<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> listBundleToUpdate = new Set<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>();
    sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c pb = new sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c();   
    Set<Id> productBundleIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Subscriber__c ss : Trigger.new) {
        if (ss.Product_Bundle__c != null) {
            productBundleIds.add(ss.Product_Bundle__c);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> productBundles = new Map<Id, sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>([
            Select id,Vision__c,Telemedicine__c,Dental__c, Fulfillment__c, name, sfcloud__Price_Book__c,sfcloud__Price_Book__r.id
            from sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c
            where Id in :productBundleIds]);

    Set<Id> priceBookIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c spb : productBundles.values()) {
        if (spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c != null) {
            priceBookIds.add(spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, List<PricebookEntry>> priceBooks = new Map<Id, List<PricebookEntry>>();
    for (PricebookEntry pbe : [
            Select Id, Name, ProductCode, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id
            From PricebookEntry
            where Pricebook2Id in :priceBookIds
            ]) {
        List<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id);
        if (l == null) {
            l = new List<PricebookEntry>();
            priceBooks.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id, l);
        }
        l.add(pbe);
    }

    for (Subscriber__c ss : Trigger.new) {        
        if (ss.Product_Bundle__c != null) {
            sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c spb = productBundles.get(ss.Product_Bundle__c);             
            List<PricebookEntry> pbe = priceBooks.get(spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c);            

            for(PricebookEntry pbe1 : pbe){    

                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Fulfillment'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Fulfillment__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Vision'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Vision__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Dental'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Dental__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Telemed_Standard'){    
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Telemedicine__c = True;
                    }                     
                }                        
                listBundleToUpdate.add(pb);                                   

        }
    }
    if(!listBundleToUpdate.isEmpty()){

        List<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> subs = new List<sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>(listBundleToUpdate);
        /*for(sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c pbb : subs){
            System.debug('My Ids'+pbb.id);
        }*/
        UPDATE subs;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that you have the same ID several times in your list `listBundleToUpdate`. Try to display the list.

Comment: Thank for Reply. I have used Set to store values then converted into list.

Comment: Rarely is the actual problem caused by the line the error is reported. That's just the line, it's caught on when the code is executed. The duplicate ID's were captured prior to that line being executed. If you showed us the rest of your code, you'd get a more complete answer to where the actual source of your problem exists.

Comment: Hello crmprogdev thanks for reply. I have update my question with full code of trigger please if you get any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section of code below could create duplicate Ids because of this line in particular:

`List<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id);`

That's because `pbe.Pricebook2Id` may not be unique for each `pbe.Id`. You'll want to rework this section using the map method recommended by @KeithC to make certain you don't have any duplicate `Pricebook2Ids` in your list. Once you have the map, you can then convert it to a list. or use your loop below to first get a set of these `Ids`, then convert the set to a `List<PriceBookEntry>`. It all depends on *how* you want to put it into the map you've named `priceBooks`.

Problematic code section:

```
for (PricebookEntry pbe : [
        Select Id, Name, ProductCode, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id
        From PricebookEntry
        where Pricebook2Id in :priceBookIds
        ]) {
    List<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id);  <--- Problematic line
        // Not certain why you're creating new entries for null PricebookEntries or if it's necessary
        // Can't tell from your code if you need these or not. 
        if (l == null) {    
        l = new List<PricebookEntry>();    
        priceBooks.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id, l);
    }
    l.add(pbe);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This pattern will not typically avoid duplicate ID values (because the set equality is based on all fields of the SObject):

```
Set<MySObject__c> sobSet = new Set<MySObject__c>();
for (...) {
    MySObject__c sob = new MySObject__c(Id = ..., ...);
    sobSet.add(sob);
}
update new List<MySObject__c>(sobSet);
```

but this pattern will:

```
Map<Id, MySObject__c> sobMap = new Map<Id, MySObject__c>();
for (...) {
    MySObject__c sob = new MySObject__c(Id = ..., ...);
    sobMap.put(sob.Id, sob);
}
update sobMap.values();
```

Note that there is still the logical error that there is more than one version of the `MySObject__c` and this code is just keeping the last one found in the loop.

This sort of error can only happen in a trigger if the update is being done on a related object (such as a parent object); the I values in the Trigger context variables will always be unique.

Comment: Assuming these records are all coming from say trigger.new or trigger.old (big assumption) and not from related records, how can a set contain two identical Ids? I'm not following your logic. I do follow the logic behind a map only being able to hold the last identical Id.

Comment: @crmprogdev There was an example yesterday in the question [Illegal assignment from LIST to SET?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53237/illegal-assignment-from-list-to-set) where the trigger was collecting parent object IDs and then trying to do an update for every child object. But I take your point that if the objects are coming from the Trigger context there won't be duplicates. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Keith. I was scratching my head trying to figure out why this one had never bit me in the proverbial rear end before. ;) This happening in the context of parent to child, or "related records" makes perfect sense to me.