# System.ListException: Duplicate id in list in Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I get System.ListException: Duplicate id in list error in my trigger code. i haven't used single list in code. i used Set and Map in all places. Following is my trigger.

```
trigger SubscriberUpdateTrigger on Subscriber__c (after Insert, after Update, after undelete) {

    Map<id,sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> listBundleToUpdate = new Map<id,sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>();
    sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c pb = new sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c();   
    Set<Id> productBundleIds = new Set<Id>();

    for (Subscriber__c ss : Trigger.new) {
        if (ss.Product_Bundle__c != null) {
            productBundleIds.add(ss.Product_Bundle__c);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c> productBundles = new Map<Id, sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c>([
            Select id,Vision__c,Telemedicine__c,Dental__c, Fulfillment__c, name, sfcloud__Price_Book__c,sfcloud__Price_Book__r.id
            from sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c
            where Id in :productBundleIds]);

    Set<Id> priceBookIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c spb : productBundles.values()) {
        if (spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c != null) {
            priceBookIds.add(spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c);
        }
    }
    Map<Id, Set<PricebookEntry>> priceBooks = new Map<Id, Set<PricebookEntry>>();
    for (PricebookEntry pbe : [
            Select Id, Name, ProductCode, Product2Id, UnitPrice, Pricebook2Id
            From PricebookEntry
            where Pricebook2Id in :priceBookIds
            ]) {
        Set<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id);
        if (l == null) {
            l = new Set<PricebookEntry>();
            priceBooks.put(pbe.Pricebook2Id, l);
        }
        l.add(pbe);
    }

    for (Subscriber__c ss : Trigger.new) {        
        if (ss.Product_Bundle__c != null) {
            sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c spb = productBundles.get(ss.Product_Bundle__c);             
            Set<PricebookEntry> pbe = priceBooks.get(spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c);            

            for(PricebookEntry pbe1 : pbe){    

                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Fulfillment'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Fulfillment__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Vision'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Vision__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Dental'){
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Dental__c = True;
                    }
                    if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Telemed_Standard'){    
                        pb.Id = spb.Id;
                        pb.Telemedicine__c = True;
                    }                     
                }                        
                listBundleToUpdate.put(spb.id,pb);                                            
        }
    }
    if(!listBundleToUpdate.isEmpty()){                
        UPDATE listBundleToUpdate.values();
    }
}
```

i get error in "UPDATE listBundleToUpdate.values()" line duplicate id.
Please help me.

Vimal

Comment: `listBundleToUpdate.values()` returns the values from the [Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm) as a List. You have obviously added the same `sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c` to the map more than once

Comment: The answer @crmprogdev provided in your question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53341/list-exception-duplicate-id-error explains why there is duplicates

Comment: Yes i can see in debug that duplicate value in listBundleToUpdate. So how i can stop to add duplicate in this list any suggestion ?

Comment: Thanks BarCotter. I have tried @crmprogdev suggestion but its not helpfull. i have used List<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id) to Set<PricebookEntry> l = priceBooks.get(pbe.Pricebook2Id); to its should not get duplicate id in set. Still facing issue. Any suggestion. If possible then please change in my given code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like below. From your map you need to load the existing object and update its fields.

```
    for (Subscriber__c ss : Trigger.new) {        
            if (ss.Product_Bundle__c != null) {
                sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c spb = productBundles.get(ss.Product_Bundle__c);  
//start new
                pb = listBundleToUpdate.get(spb.id);           
                if(pb = null){                                                
                    pb = new sfcloud__Product_Bundle__c();
                    pb.id = spb.id;
                }
//end new
                Set<PricebookEntry> pbe = priceBooks.get(spb.sfcloud__Price_Book__c);            

                for(PricebookEntry pbe1 : pbe){

                        if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Fulfillment'){
                            pb.Fulfillment__c = True;
                        }
                        if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Vision'){
                            pb.Vision__c = True;
                        }
                        if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Discount_Dental'){
                            pb.Dental__c = True;
                        }
                        if(pbe1.ProductCode == 'Telemed_Standard'){    
                            pb.Telemedicine__c = True;
                        }                     
                    }                        
                    listBundleToUpdate.put(spb.id,pb);                                            
            }
        }

        UPDATE listBundleToUpdate.values();
```