# Handling Duplicate Id in List Exception

Tags: apex, exception, junction-object

I have junction object `ProjectxOpp__c` which links Projects (`MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c`) with Opportunities. It's a many to many relationship so the same Opportunity can be linked to multiple Projects.

When I update my Project record's `MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c` field, I also want to update Opportunities which are linked to that Project by an `ProjectxOpp__c` junction record.
If I update a batch of Projects & as a result, update a batch of related Opportunities, it's possible that I end up trying to update the same Opportunity twice. This causes a System.ListException

> Duplicate id in list

I've seen several solutions on the site for dealing with this issue but they either suggest rewriting an earlier section of the code, to avoid picking up the same record twice or using a [Map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53341/list-exception-duplicate-id-error) to store the Ids & I can't see how to apply the latter solution in my code.

Neither explain how to handle duplicates that you're expecting..

```
trigger WE_IMProjCmpltnUp on MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c (after insert, after update) {

    Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> RT = MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName();
    List<VRTN__c> weRTs = VRTN__c.getall().values();
    List<String> weRTNames = new List<String>();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    Set<Id> projects = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Date> deadlineDates = new Map<Id,Date>();
    List<Opportunity> updOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(VRTN__c weRT : weRTs) {
        try {
            weRTNames.add(weRT.NAEUProjs__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Invalid Record Type Name ' + weRT.NAEUOpps__c);
        }
    }

    for(String weRTN : weRTNames) {
        if(RT.get(weRTN) != null){
            validRecordTypeIds.add(RT.get(weRTN).getRecordTypeId());
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
            if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
            {
                projects.add(p.Id);
                deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
            }
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isUpdate){
                for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
                    if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
                    {
                        MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c oldP = Trigger.oldMap.get(p.Id);

                        if(oldP.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c){
                            projects.add(p.Id);
                            deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }

    If(projects.size() > 0){

        for(ProjectxOpp__c junc : [SELECT Project__c, Opportunity__r.Implementation_Revenue__c FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                    WHERE Project__c In :projects])
        {
            Opportunity o = junc.Opportunity__r;
            Date newCompDate =  deadlineDates.get(junc.Project__c);
            if(newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c){
                o.Implementation_Revenue__c = newCompDate;
            }
            updOpps.add(o);
        }
        update updOpps;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its a limitation with List that you cannot have multiple records with same Id during DML. using Sets / Maps as you already referred is the way to solve this.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna thanks, I had considered Sets but the DML needs an SObject / SObject list. I don't understand how using a Map would resolve the issue?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna actually are Maps the solution because ['Adding a map entry with a key that matches an existing key in the map overwrites the existing entry with that key with the new entry.'](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm)? If so, is placing the results of the SOQL query in a Map & then processing them the most efficient approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can have multiple `MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c` objects related to an `Opportunity` and your aim is to record the latest `MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c` date from any of them.

Here is one way to do that:

```
Map<Id, Opportunity> updates = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
Map<Id, Opportunity> m = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
for(ProjectxOpp__c j : [
        SELECT Project__c, Opportunity__r.Id, Opportunity__r.Implementation_Revenue__c
        FROM ProjectxOpp__c
        WHERE Project__c In :projects
        AND Opportunity__c != null
        ]) {
    Id oppId = j.Opportunity__r.Id
    Opportunity opp = m.get(oppId);
    if (opp == null) {
        opp = j.Opportunity__r;
        m.put(oppId, opp);
    }
    Date newCompDate = deadlineDates.get(j.Project__c);
    if (newCompDate > opp.Implementation_Revenue__c){
        opp.Implementation_Revenue__c = newCompDate;
        updates.put(oppId, opp);
    }
}
update updates.values();
```

The aim is to update each `Opportunity` once only: that can be done by using a map (called `m` here) keyed by the ID so there is only ever one instance of `Opportunity` kept even though many duplicates may be returned by the query. The map can be populated from your existing query: if there isn't an entry in the map it is added.

I've also added a second map (called `updates`) because only some of the `Opportunity` objects will need to updated.

Comment: @Alex I've hopefully applied them to the answer.